# Choice prompt does not render buttons in MS Bot framework

Tags: botframework

I'm using Nodejs SDK and sending a choice promot to the user like this :

```
builder.Prompts.choice(
                session,
                bot_response,
                "Yes|No",
                {
                    maxRetries: 3,
                    retryPrompt: 'Sorry, that is not a valid input'
                },
                { 
                    listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button 
                }
            );
```

This is how it is rendered:

[image]

How do I make it render it in button style?

Comment: Which channel(s) are you trying to render the buttons on? The ability to render a button vs. a list being generated is channel specific. This is likely the roadblock you are running into.

Comment: Reference this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163672/what-is-the-correct-way-to-render-options-list-as-buttons-in-choice-prompt/53163701#53163701

Comment: @StevenKanberg Im using Webchat channel

Comment: anyupdate here ?